# How to change browser router depending on the type of user logged in

Tags: reactjs, typescript, meteor, react-router, meteor-accounts

I am building a web app using Meteor.js with React. The app has two types of users: "user" and "employer", each with their own routes (like different dashboards and other pages). So I have a `UserRouter`, an `EmployerRouter`, and an `UnprotectedRouter` (for when the user is not logged in yet). I want to return a different router depending on which user is logged in (I have a "type" field to let me know which user type they are). The issue is that the router is not updating when a user logs in. Basically I need different routers depending not only on if the user is logged in or not, but what TYPE of user it is.

I tried to use `useState`, but it wouldn't update the router. Then I thought because the browser reroutes after the user signs up, maybe it would rerun `App.tsx` which would update the router to the correct one, but that did not work either. Right now when I start up the app, it renders the `UnprotectedRouter` because I'm not logged in. Then when I go to the sign-up form and create a new user (which logs me in automatically), it still shows `UnprotectedRouter` rather than `UserRouter`.

This is what my code currently looks like:

## UserRouter.tsx

```
export const UserRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path={RoutePaths.USER_HOME} element={<UserHome />} />
      <Route path={RoutePaths.USER_PROFILE} element={<UserProfile />} />
      <Route path={RoutePaths.EMPLOYER_HOME} element={<EmployerHome />} />
      <Route path={RoutePaths.USER_SIGNUP} element={<UserSignUp />} />
      <Route path={RoutePaths.EMPLOYER_SIGNUP} element={<EmployerSignUp />} />
      <Route path={RoutePaths.USER_SIGNIN} element={<UserSignIn />} />
      <Route path="/position/:postingId" element={<UserPosting />}/>
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

## EmployerRouter.tsx

```
export const EmployerRouter = () => {
    return (
      <Routes>
        <Route path={RoutePaths.USER_HOME} element={<EmployerDashboard />} />
      </Routes>
    );
  };
```

## UnprotectedRouter.tsx

```
export const UnprotectedRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path={RoutePaths.WELCOME_PAGE} element={<WelcomePage />} />
      <Route path={RoutePaths.USER_SIGNUP} element={<UserSignUp />} />
      <Route path={RoutePaths.EMPLOYER_SIGNUP} element={<EmployerSignUp />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

## App.tsx

```
const selectRouter = (userType: String) => {
  switch (userType) {
    case "user":
      return <UserRouter />
    case "employer":
      return <EmployerRouter />
    default:
      return <UnprotectedRouter />
  }
}

const RouterChoice = () => {
  const isLoadingProfiles = useSubscribe("allUserProfiles");
  const loggedInUsername = Meteor.user()?.username;
  const userType = UserCollection.findOne({ username: loggedInUsername })?.type;

  return selectRouter(userType)
}

export const App = () => {
  const router = RouterChoice();

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        {router}
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
};
```

This is what my sign-up method for users looks like:

```js
const handleSignUp = (e: { preventDefault: () => void }) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("password is: " + password);
  console.log("username is: " + username);
  console.log("email is: " + email);
  Accounts.createUser(
    {
      username: username,
      password: password,
      email: email,
    },
    (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
      } else {
        console.log("success!");
      }
    }
  );

  Meteor.call("user-profile.createNewProfile", {
    username: username,
    name: name,
    type: "user",
  });

  setName("");
  setUsername("");
  setEmail("");
  setPassword("");
  console.log("submitted!");
  navigate(RoutePaths.USER_HOME);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have rendered is on App.tsx you need to wrap

```
const router = RouterChoice();
```

By a

```
useEffect(() => {}, [])
```

Like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const router = RouterChoice();
}, [Meteor.user()?.username])
```

For the dependency I used <<Meteor.user()?.username>> but you should use what changes when the user logs in with a different account.

Answer (score 0):

The issue it seems is that you have incorrectly cased the `RouterChoice` function name which "tricks" React, or rather "Rules of Hooks", into thinking that `RouterChoice` is a React component instead of a regular callback function. `RouterChoice` calls a `useSubscribe` React hook, but because `App` isn't triggered to rerender it doesn't call the `useSubscribe` again because `RouterChoice` is never "called" again as a React component.

Rename `RouterChoice` to something like `useRouterChoice` so it's called validly as a custom React hook.

```
const selectRouter = (userType: String) => {
  switch (userType) {
    case "user":
      return <UserRouter />;
    case "employer":
      return <EmployerRouter />;
    default:
      return <UnprotectedRouter />;
  }
};

const useRouterChoice = () => {
  const isLoadingProfiles = useSubscribe("allUserProfiles");
  const loggedInUsername = Meteor.user()?.username;
  const userType = UserCollection.findOne({ username: loggedInUsername })?.type;

  return selectRouter(userType);
};

export const App = () => {
  const router = useRouterChoice();

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        {router}
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

The issue you might run into now is when the auth state/condition changes that the UI and other routes might not be mounted and navigatable to just yet. For this it's better to unconditionally render all the routes and protect/guard access to the routes.

Here's a common route protection implementation using layout routes.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ type }: { type: "user" | "employer"}) => {
  const isLoadingProfiles = useSubscribe("allUserProfiles");

  const loggedInUsername = Meteor.user()?.username;
  const userType = UserCollection.findOne({ username: loggedInUsername })?.type;

  if (isLoadingProfiles) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return userType === type
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};
```

```
export const App = () => {
  const router = useRouterChoice();

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Routes>
          {/* unprotected routes */}

          <Route element={<ProtectedRoute type="user" />}>
            {/* protected user routes */}
          </Route>
          <Route element={<ProtectedRoute type="employer" />}>
            {/* protected employer routes */}
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

If you want the "unprotected" routes to not be accessible by authenticated users then protect them with another layout route component that applies the inverse logic of the `ProtectedRoute` component.

```
const AnonymousRoute = () => {
  const isLoadingProfiles = useSubscribe("allUserProfiles");

  const loggedInUsername = Meteor.user()?.username;
  const userType = UserCollection.findOne({ username: loggedInUsername })?.type;

  if (isLoadingProfiles) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return !!userType
    ? <Navigate to={/* any safe authenticated/protected route path */} replace />
    : <Outlet />;
};
```

```
export const App = () => {
  const router = useRouterChoice();

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<AnonymousRoute />}>
            {/* unprotected routes */}
          </Route>
          <Route element={<ProtectedRoute type="user" />}>
            {/* protected user routes */}
          </Route>
          <Route element={<ProtectedRoute type="employer" />}>
            {/* protected employer routes */}
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hello, I'm a little confused on implementing this. When I know I'm logged in (because Meteor.user() in the console returns a user object), loggedInUsername and userType are both undefined? I console.logged those two variables and they keep printing out "undefined" but I know I'm definitely logged in. 

I'm also a little confused on how the route protection works. In my signup form, it redirects the user when they sign in. Is it like, it would recognize that path as being a child of the ProtectedRoute with type="user" and do the whole loggedInUsername thing and then redirect?

Comment: @Kaley So `Meteor.user()` is a defined object? What properties are on that object? If `UserCollection.findOne` finds a match, what are the properties on *that* object/reference? I have absolutely no familiarity with Meteor, are some of these functions asynchronous? As for how the route protection works, yes, the protected routes are children of the "guard" layout route that checks the user's auth status and conditionally renders the route content or redirects off the protected route.